# Browser HTML5 turn-based multiplayer game with ASP.NET (MVC 4) reasonable?

Tags: asp.net, html, browser, multiplayer

as the title says, I want to develop a browser multiplayer game with HTML5. 
The game will be something like "risk", the turn-based strategy game. I decided to develop with HTML5 and the new canvas.

But the problem is on the server side. When I google, I only get answers, where people use "System.io", "node.js" etc. for that.

So my question is:

Is ASP.NET - especially MVC 4 - a bad choice for my purpose? I would like to do that with asp.net, but of course not when there is an easier/more suited option.

Some people say asp.net is not suited for that, it's too complicated and so on.

But I ask you pros out there :D

Would you consider developing a game like that with asp.net mvc 4 or better stick to other solutions with system.io and node.js and other frameworks? (php?)

I hope you can help my out, that stresses me for weeks now :(

Thanks in Advance!

Greetings from Munich

Tornister

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Asp.net, especially MVC is well suited to develop an html5 based game.

A turn based game, is not very different from a web based chat. Where you send messages between members via the server.

To design a scalable solution, you got to use the right methods though.

You have various options to communicate between users.

Libraries like [SignalR](http://signalr.net/) would help. If you do want to do it yourself, the most efficient method is to use a [IHttpAsyncHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ihttpasynchandler.aspx) and ajax requests. In MVC the equivalend it [AsyncController](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.asynccontroller.aspx).

Frameworks like node.js are designed to be async, and thus well suited. Php out of the box is not a good choice for such applications as it doesn't support async requests.

To sum it up, asp.net is not a bad choice, but you need to know how to use it. If you are more comfortable with another framework like node.js, then you should choose that one. Familiarity reduces a lot of development time.

Comment: I'm familiar with Windows Services programming, will it reduce the development time, too? ;-)

Comment: :-) Visual studio is a great IDE, i say! Saves a lot of time. So long as you are using the same programming language, that will help reduce time too.